# Split array into multiple parts and output string with list of values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list

I am trying to figure out how to break down/partition an array of values from the database and turn the individual lists into a string of values seperated by a comma.

If I don't partition the list from the query I can get the whole list to display in the format that I want using this.

```
<?php

$get_values = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");

$value_list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_values))
{
$value_list[] = $row['value'];
}

foreach( $value_list as $key => $value )
print_r($value . ", ");

//Outputs all values with comma as a list.
//value0, value1, value2, ... value25

?>
```

In this code I cant figure out how to get the lists "$values" to output correctly unless I define $values[0] or $values[1] etc in the foreach loop but that obviously only gives me one list.
If I just use $values in the foreach loop I get an Array to string error. The data is dynamic and I use more code to define and partition list sizes for larger amounts of results besides the 2 shown in the code that split the list into 4 and 8 parts.

```
<?php

$get_values = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");

$value_list = array();
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_values))
{
$counter++;
$value_list[] = $row['value'];
}

//Partition into  4 or 8 lists depending on amount of values returned
if($counter >=0 && $counter <=100 )
{
$values = partition($value_list, 4);
}
if($counter >=100 && $counter <=200 )
{
$values = partition($value_list, 8);
}

foreach( $values[0] as $key => $value )
print_r($value . ", ");

function partition(Array $list, $p) {
$listlen = count($list);
$partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
$partrem = $listlen % $p;
$partition = array();
$mark = 0;
for($px = 0; $px < $p; $px ++) {
    $incr = ($px < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
    $partition[$px] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
    $mark += $incr;
}
return $partition;
}

?>
```

Is there anything I can do to get the output that I want from all of the lists so that I can use the lists or process them later on in small batches?

What I want is the individual lists from the main partitioned list to output in the same format as the entire list from the first script.
Example:

```
list0:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
list1:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
list2:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
list3:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
list4:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
list5:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
list6:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
list7:
value0, value1, value2, ... value25
```

Here is an example of what the array output looks like after using the partition function with about 200 results.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => value0
            [1] => value1
            [2] => value2
             ...
             ...
             ...
            [25] => value25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value0
            [1] => value1
            [2] => value2
             ...
             ...
             ...
            [25] => value25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => value0
            [1] => value1
            [2] => value2
             ...
             ...
             ...
            [25] => value25
        )

     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => value0
            [1] => value1
            [2] => value2
             ...
             ...
             ...
            [25] => value25

        )

)
```

Comment: This question isn't very clear. The last dump showed that you are getting an array of arrays. This should let you easily loop through them, outputting them in groups of (in this case) 25: ``foreach ( $values as $i => $a ) { echo "List $i: " . join( ', ', $a ); }``. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Looks like it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The last dump showed that you are getting an array of arrays. This should let you easily loop through them, outputting them in groups of (in this case) 25:

```
foreach ( $values as $i => $a ) {
    echo "List $i: " . join( ', ', $a );
}
```